# C branch on static variable optimization

Tags: c, optimization, branch, control-flow

Let me preface this by saying I haven't profiled this code, nor is it a critical path. This is mostly for my own curiosity.

I have a function that declares/defines a static int to a known error value that will cause the code to take a branch. However, if the function succeeds, I know with certainty that the branch will never be taken again. Is there a compile time optimization for this? Specifically GNU/gcc/glibc?

So I have this:

```
static unsigned long volatile *getReg(unsigned long addr){

    static int fd = -1;

    if (fd < 0){
        if (fd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) < 0){
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

So once the function completes successfully (if this function returns null, I exit the program), I know that fd will for all future calls be valid and will never take the first branch. I know there's the __builtin_expect() macro, so I could write

```
if (__builtin_expect((fd<0),0){
```

But from what I understand that's only a HINT to the compiler, and it still has to perform the condition check. And I also realize it will in 99.9999% of the cases be more than enough so that any further performance increase is negligible.

I was wondering if there was a way of preventing even the first condition check (the fd <0 ) after the very first time it gets run.

Comment: Short of self-modifying code, I don't believe that there's a way to avoid a conditional (or equivalently, function pointers) in a situation where you expect behaviour that differs based on a condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one of the ways to fix this would be to use a function pointer to call the method. Initialize the function ptr to your long function and at the end of the first call set it to the version without additional initialization.

That said, it sounds like an absolute maintenance nightmare and is surely not worth to avoid one branch - but you get rid of the branch.. (and certainly get rid of any chance that the function is inlined which depending on how long the function is will be almost certainly detrimental)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, since it actually sounds like the most accurate answer. I didn't think about switching function pointers.

Comment: It is also almost certainly going to be _slower_ than the simple implementation, because indirect calls are slower than direct calls (potentially hundreds of times slower).  So this is harder to implement, harder to read, and slower...  But other than that, a perfect answer.  (Incidentally, this is what I was referring to when I mentioned "tricks with pointers to functions".)

Comment: Yeah. I understand the fact that it will be slower. My question wasn't so much for performance optimization. I was more thinking about, what if the condition check itself had side effects that you didn't want? Or the check itself could cause an error if run after an error condition? (I know, refactor the check/state, obviously =P)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "no".

I mean, sure, you could maybe play tricks with pointers to functions, monkey-patching your code, etc., but that would almost certainly be slower than just doing the test.

Branches are only expensive when they are mis-predicted.  `__builtin_expect` will arrange to ensure that this branch is only mis-predicted the first time.

You are talking about literally one or two cycles here, and possibly not even that, depending on what else the CPU is doing near this code.

[update]

If something like this really is being called millions or billions of times per second, you would deal with it by restructuring your code to initialize `fd` early and then use it repeatedly without bothering to test.  For example, you might add an `initGlobalState();` call near the top of main() and open the file then.  (You would want a corresponding `destroyGlobalState();` to close it again.)

And of course, a file descriptor is a horrible example, because anything you are doing to it will take vastly more than one or two cycles anyway.

In C++, constructors, destructors, and the [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) makes this sort of approach very natural, by the way.

Comment: +1: Agreed.  Of course, in some situations that couple of cycles could be significant, if the function is being called millions of times per second.

Comment: I agree with you both. The condition check is insignificant. But like I said, this is purely for education and hactucational purposes =]

Comment: @Oli:  Except the function call itself will take longer than that...  But I think I will add an update.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nemo: Except if it's inlined!

Comment: @Nemo: Sometimes if function call takes less, it is still better to inline. In fact, compiler will not inline, but clone and place code near the caller, which in turn may avoid lots of memory being transferred back and forth between main memory and caches. It depends.

Comment: +1 for "And of course, a file descriptor is a horrible example, because anything you are doing to it will take vastly more than one or two cycles anyway."

Comment: @R: The file descriptor is pointing to /dev/mem which, after this piece of code in this function, gets mmapped. So it's not TOTALLY contrived.

Answer (score 2):

Split the function in two, in their own source file ... and let the caller worry about it :)

```
static int fd;

unsigned long volatile *getReg(unsigned long addr) {
  /* do stuff with fd and addr */
  return 0;
}

int getRegSetup(void) {
  fd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
  if (fd < 0) return 1;                /* error */
  /* continue processing */
  return 0;                            /* ok */
}
```

The caller then does

```
  /* ... */
  if (getRegSetup()) {
    /* error */
  } else {
    do {
      ptr = getReg(42);
    } while (ptr);
  }
  /* ... */
```

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the condition check though. It just moves it elsewhere. ANd now it's several instructions longer because it has to lookup the function address and etc.

Comment: The condition is only tested once, even if you need to call `getReg` a million times

Comment: @Falmarri, it _does_ eliminate it on all calls to `getReg`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: But you've just moved the condition to checking `getRegSetup()` instead of checking fd < 0. Yes, that particular condition is tested once, but there's still A condition being checked on every call.

Comment: The loop (added to the answer) is in the else block!

Comment: You're made an assumption about the flow of code. There is no loop. This function is called based on CPU interrupts.

Comment: @pmg, that code sample has no advantage, you would be better off showing code that called setup outside a loop and getreg within the loop.

Comment: @Falmarri, if it's interrupt based, you can use the same trick. Open the file before enabling interrupts then remove the check from the ISR altogether.

Comment: @Falmarri: I made assumptions to illustrate the workings of the code. It doesn't matter if it's a loop or a interrupt ... just move the code around.

Comment: @paxdiablo: The problem is I don't have control over the interrupts, or when (in the boot sequence) my code runs, especially since it is from userspace. My code is simply called in userspace after being notified of the interrupt. But like I said, this is not really related since my question was almost entirely educational. This is in fact part of a native python module, so yeah, just an educational question =P

Answer (score 0):

`__builtin_expect` is only a hint. It helps compiler to generate better code. For example, re-arrange jump labels so that mainline code is continually aligned in memory, which makes it more friendly for code cache lines, easier to fetch from main memory etc. Running profile guided optimization is even better.

I don't see any locking in your code, so I assume this function is not supposed to be called from multiple threads at the same time. In this case you have to move `fd` out of the function scope, so that double checked locking is not applied. Then, re-arrange the code a bit (that's what GCC supposed to do with branch hints, but you know...). Plus, you can copy a file descriptor from main memory / cache line into a register if you access it often. The code will look something like this:

```
static int g_fd = -1;

static unsigned long volatile *getReg(unsigned long addr)
{
    register int fd = g_fd;

    if (__builtin_expect ((fd > 0), 1))
    {
on_success:
        return NULL; // Do important stuff here.
    }

    fd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

    if (__builtin_expect ((fd > 0), 1))
    {
        g_fd = fd;
        goto on_success;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

But please don't take this seriously. System calls and file I/O are so bad so optimizing stuff like this doesn't make any sense (with some exceptions).

And if you really want to call it once, then you better off moving file open into a separate function that is called once, and before everything else. And yes, take a look at GCC`s profile feedback and LTO. That will help you achieve good results without spending too much time on stuff like this.

Comment: __builtin_expect does more than that; it actually helps the compiler's branch prediction.  Default branch prediction is to assume forward branches are not taken and backward branches are taken.  (This can change dynamically during run time as the CPU keeps track of how often each branch was taken.)  If you compile for (e.g.) x86_64 with different settings of __builtin_expect and look at the assembly, you will see this is exactly what it is doing (i.e. assume forward branch = not taken, backward branch = taken).  On some architectures, __builtin_expect actually sets a bit in the branch insn

Comment: @Nemo does __builtin_expect set predicates on x86? No idea if those are useful with modern CPUs or not, but it sounds like it could do that.

Comment: @Voo: x86 does not have prediction bits in the branch instructions, but __builtin_expect will cause GCC to re-arrange the generated code to match the CPU's default prediction heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious, this is what I came up with. Note that this is a module to a larger, long running program. Also, that it hasn't been reviewed, and is basically a bad hack anyway.

```
__attribute__((noinline)) static unsigned int volatile *get_mem(unsigned int addr) {
    static void *map = 0 ;
    static unsigned prevPage = -1U ;
    static int fd = -1;
    int poss_err = 0;
    register unsigned page = addr & ~MAP_MASK ;

    if ( unlikely(fd < 0) ) {
        if ((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) < 0) {
            longjmp(mem_err, errno);
        }
    }
    if ( page != prevPage ) {
        if ( map ) {
            if (unlikely((munmap(map,MAP_SIZE) < 0))) poss_err = 1;
        }
        if (unlikely((map = mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, page )) == MAP_FAILED)) longjmp(mem_err, errno);

        prevPage = page ;
    }
    return (unsigned int volatile *)((char *)map+(addr & MAP_MASK));
}

static void set_reg(const struct reg_info * const r, unsigned int val)
{
    unsigned int volatile * const mem = get_mem(r->addr);
    *mem = (*mem & (~(r->mask << r->shift))) | (val << r->shift);
}

// This isn't in the final piece. There are several entry points into this module. Just an example

static int entryPoint(unsigned int value){

    if (setjmp(mem_err)!=0) {
        // Serious error
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (strlen(regs[i].name) == strlen(name) &&
                strncmp(regs[i].name, name, strlen (name))==0) {

            set_reg(&regs[i], value);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously isn't an answer to the question, since it checks the condition on every call.